# Show SQL data in Chart.JS

Tags: php, chart.js

I'm trying to get a chart.js bar chart to pull results from a SQL database, at the moment, it's showing the background of the chart but none of the data on it and no errors are being displayed.

I have the following getBarchartData.php

```
<?
$connect = odbc_connect("Description=PCD_SQL_SERVER;DRIVER=SQL 
Server;SERVER=gbsuk0pcdspdsql","smt24PointUser","ForeRunnerQC19");

$SQL = "SELECT totalScore, dateofAudit
FROM table1
WHERE dateOfAudit >= DATEADD(day,-14, GETDATE()) and lineAudited = 'Reflow 
2'
GROUP BY lineAudited, totalScore, dateofAudit
ORDER BY len(lineAudited), lineAudited asc";

$result = odbc_exec($connect,$SQL);

$data = array();

if (is_array($result) || is_object($result))
{
foreach ($result as $row) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
}

print json_encode($data);
?>
```

And I have the following dashboard.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js">
</script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script>

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'getBarChartData.php',
dataType: 'json', //tell jQuery to parse received data as JSON before 
passing it onto successCallback
success: function (data) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data //jQuery will parse this since dataType is set to json
    });
}
});

</script>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here for the data not be showing.

Comment: Does the chart work with "static" data not coming from DB? You can use your browser's DevTools Network tab to make sure your `getBarChartData.php` returns the correct data

Comment: Yes it does work with static data